# Does Linux kernel 3.x use the CFS process scheduler?

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduling

Does the latest version of the Linux kernel (3.x)  still use the Completely Fair Scheduler (CFS) for process scheduling which was introduced in 2.6.x ?

If it doesn't, which one does it use, and how does it work? Please provide a source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's still the default, yes, though I would not call it the same, as it is constantly in development. You can read how it works with links to the code at http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does. It is the default scheduler in 3.x series but the kernel now has a realtime scheduler also built-in but disabled by default.

More on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel

Answer (score 0):

This, in my opinion is the easiest to digest explanation on CFS: [Process Scheduling in Linux, for kernel 3, chapter 7](https://criticalblue.com/news/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/linux_scheduler_notes_final.pdf)

Also, at the end of the article there are more links on the topic.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  Links die.  Although other answers have links as well they have at least one sentence explaining things.  You need to expand you post.